# Validate if JSON has a determined structure on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, soap

I haven't found a way to determine this on a efficient way on PHP, but here is the issue: I'm currently a begineer on building web services, but so far I have made one using PHP SOAP. I know REST is better but I don't quite understand how to do it. The thing is here:

Web Service code:

```
<?php

if (!extension_loaded("soap")) {
    dl("php_soap.dll");
}
require_once '../modulos/conexion.php'; //conecta a BD

function net_receive($token, $tabla, $json_encode) {
    $val_token = '8mp8';
    $json_query = json_decode($json_encode, true);
    if ($val_token == $token) {
        switch ($tabla) {
            case 'cabusuarios':
                $receiver_msg = cab_usuarios($json_query, $tabla);
                break;
            case 'detusuarios':
                $receiver_msg = det_usuarios($json_query, $tabla);
                break;
            case 'cabdatos':
                $receiver_msg = cab_datos($json_query, $tabla);
                break;
            case 'detdatos':
                $receiver_msg = det_datos($json_query, $tabla);
                break;
            case 'itinerario':
                $receiver_msg = itinerario($json_query, $tabla);
                break;
            case 'mconsigna':
                $receiver_msg = mconsigna($json_query, $tabla);
                break;
            case 'mvende':
                $receiver_msg = mvende($json_query, $tabla);
                break;
            default:
                $receiver_msg = $tabla . ' no es un nombre de tabla valido';
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $receiver_msg = 'Token de autenticacion no valido';
    }
    return $receiver_msg;
}

function cab_usuarios($json_query, $tabla) {
    foreach ($json_query as $row) {
        $id_usua = $row["id_usua"];
        $co_usua = $row["co_usua"];
        $no_usua = $row["no_usua"];
        $ds_pass = password_hash($row["ds_pass"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $st_usua = $row["st_usua"];
        $fe_ingre = date_format(date_create_from_format('d-m-Y H:i:s', $row['fe_ingre']), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $co_user = $row["co_user"];
        $eTInf = $row["eTInf"];
        $aTSuc = $row["aTSuc"];
        $aTInf = date_format(date_create_from_format('d-m-Y H:i:s', $row['aTInf']), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $co_vende = $row["co_vende"];
        $query .= "INSERT INTO dbfar_" . $tabla . " (`id_usua`, `co_usua`, `no_usua`, `ds_pass`, `st_usua`, `fe_ingre`, `co_user`, `eTInf`, `aTSuc`, `aTlnf`, `co_vende`) VALUES ($id_usua,'$co_usua','$no_usua', '$ds_pass', '$st_usua', '$fe_ingre', '$co_user', $eTInf, '$aTSuc', '$aTInf', $co_vende);";
    }
    return (SQL_queries($query, $tabla));
}

function SQL_queries($query, $tabla) {
    $multiquery = mysqli_multi_query($GLOBALS['conexion'], $query);
    if (!$multiquery) {
        $query_Status = "Query en " . $tabla . " presenta errores";
    } else {
        $query_Status = "Query realizado en " . $tabla . " correctamente";
    }
    cerrar_conexion_sql();
    return ($query_Status);
}

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$server = new SoapServer('farletza.wsdl');

$server->addFunction("net_receive");

$server->handle();
```

To explain it in short words, function net_receive gets three variables: token for security purpose, tabla which is the name of a table on mysql, and json_encode which is a JSON that has all the fields and data.

The thing is if tabla has one of the values listed on the fields, it will call a function which gets the JSON values and builds up the query, SQL_queries just inserts them and returns if query was succesful or not. The other functions for other tables are similar, only changing on the name and amount of fields. But now I need to validate if all the required properties on the JSON exists, and I don't want to use

```
if( isset( $json_query['id_usua'] ) ){
}
```

To validate if every field does have a value, but won't tell me if there is a missing property, and it would be writing a lot of code. How can I do this?

Here are the variables I use for testing

```
$token = "8mp8";
$tabla = "cabusuarios";
$json = '[{"id_usua": "3","co_usua": "david ortega", "no_usua": "usuario 2", "ds_pass": "1234", "st_usua": "A", "fe_ingre":"12-04-2015 00:00:00", "co_user": "00084", "eTInf": "0", "aTSuc": "FAR", "aTInf": "", "co_vende": "2"}'
        . ',{"id_usua": "4","co_usua": "jonathan", "no_usua": "usuario 3", "ds_pass": "1234", "st_usua": "A", "fe_ingre":"12-04-2015 00:00:00", "co_user": "00084", "eTInf": "0", "aTSuc": "FAR", "aTInf": "", "co_vende": "2"}]';
```

Comment: How to validate if a JSON has all the properties I need it to have. Maybe I didn't state it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert all the required fields into an array and perform a check after json_decode with an array_diff().

```
/**
 * List of mandatory fields
 */
$pattern = array('param1', 'param2', 'param3');

/**
 * check presence of the keys in the json_decoded object
 */
 $check = !array_diff(json_decode($yourRequest, true), $pattern);
```

note : If you want check also the consistency of the input params contained in the json string you could use array_filter() to purge empty values befor to perform array_diff().

```
$in = array_filter(json_decode($yourRequest, true));
/**
 * List of mandatory fields
 */
$pattern = array('param1', 'param2', 'param3');

/**
 * check presence of the keys in the json_decoded object
 */
 $check = !array_diff($in, $pattern);
```

Comment: Sorry for late marking, this way indeed helped me more, not because other answers were wrong but implementing this as a class allowed to validate more type of data, not only JSON

Answer (score 0):

This may be more than you want, but if you really want to validate JSON data, you can use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) to define the required data structure, including which values are required and optional and the valid range for each value. You would then use a [PHP JSON Schema validator](https://github.com/geraintluff/jsv4-php) to test whether the incoming data matches the schema.

This approach is more complex but could make sense if the data is coming from an untrusted source. You’d also want to [use placeholders](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to protect your database from SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You could create one array to validate the json array using array functions:

```
<?php
// test data
$jsonData = array(
        "id_usua" => "test",
        "co_usua" => "test",
        "no_usua" => "test",
        #"ds_pass" => "test",
        "st_usua" => "test",
        'fe_ingre' => "test",
        "co_user" => "test",
        "eTInf" => "test",
        "aTSuc" => "test",
        'aTInf' => "test",
        "co_vende" => ""
);

$validJsonFields = array(
    "id_usua","co_usua","no_usua",
    "ds_pass","st_usua",'fe_ingre',
    "co_user","eTInf","aTSuc",
    'aTInf',"co_vende"
);

$missingKeys = array_diff($validJsonFields,array_keys($jsonData));
function _empty($x){ return empty($x); }
$emptyFields = array_keys(array_filter($jsonData,'_empty'));


var_dump($missingKeys,$emptyFields);
/*
    array(1) {
      [3] =>
      string(7) "ds_pass"
    }
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      string(8) "co_vende"

}
 */
```